# Removing unused .m files

Tags: file, matlab

I have a Matlab GUI file, that uses several other .m files (all of them in the same directory as the GUI file) for working. I would like to remove any other file in the current directory that isn´t used by the GUI file. How could I do it easily and without any risk of removing any file needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the dependency analysis offered in the editors *tools* menu.
This gives you an option to run the report on the Current Folder, which you can inspect to spot unused .m files. Other than this, I'm not aware of an automated way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks! It´s a great answer. To access that option: "Actions button" on the directories interface -> Reports -> Dependency Report

Answer (score 3):

There is an automated way - run the function `depfun`, it will give you the list of the dependencies.

Comment: It may be much more slower than the "Dependency report" action, but it may be less prone to errors.